# How to access a ndjson file and find the oldest person, average age, youngest person in the country. Is it possible with python or javascript only

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, ndjson

[image]

Is it possible to open with python or javascript if so, how do I access the file and find the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

You just do it, line by line.

```
import json
data = []
for line in open('ndjson.json'):
    data.append( json.loads(line) )
```